# NullPointerException from PrintWriter class and File creation

Tags: java, exception, file-io

I've been working on a small bit of code and though the rest of the code works, there is an error with the logging system that I've written.

When the method log(String) is called, it throws a NullPointerException.
I thought this might be because the file might not be being created, but I'm not sure what I've done wrong and as far as I can tell the file should be being created (It's not) and even if I create the file and put it into the correct position, the exception is still thrown.

I've been tinkering around with it a bit, so some of it doesn't make sense, it's probably because it was while I was debugging.

Here's the code:

```
package UI;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;



public class InputLogger {

//Necessary for interceptor pattern

private static PrintWriter output;

//For testing remove later
private static File logFile;

public InputLogger() {
    initiate("log.txt");
}
public InputLogger(String anotherFile) {
    initiate(anotherFile);
}

public void initiate(String filename) {
    try {
        /*File */logFile = new File(filename);
        if(!logFile.exists()) {
            if(!logFile.createNewFile())
                System.err.println("Error creating log file. Please verify that files can be created.");
        }
        output = new PrintWriter(logFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error accessing log file. Please verify that files can be created.");
    }
}

public static void log(String action) {

    try {
        output.println(action);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        System.err.println("Error printing to log file. Please verify that file exists or can be created.");
    }
}

public void close() {
    output.close();
}
}
```

I think it might have something to do with the fact that I call it as a static method, but I've been looking around and I can't seem to find an explanation elsewhere.

Edit:
I forgot to actually create an InputLogger object. Thanks guys.

Comment: How did you create a Logger and call log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you forgot to create an InputLogger object. Do this:

```
InputLogger logger = new InputLogger();
InputLogger.log( "hoooey" );
logger.close();
```

Not calling close may lose a line or two.

Mixing static with a constructor and proper methods is dangerous, and an antipattern. You might remain with static, with a lazy initialization which gives your program the chance to set the file name. Or, better, avoid the statics and do all in proper methods.

Comment: That seems to have worked. I had initialised it, but I removed it for a reason I can't recall. Thanks.

I am trying static for now because it is called by a number of ActionListeners, and I thought this would be easier than having to put the InputLogger into each listener.

I had tried it at first, but it was causing a lot of circular dependency and overcomplication and so I tried using Static and it worked mostly.

Thanks again. It never ceases to amaze me how quickly people can get back to me with the exact answer with such limited (To me) information.

Answer (score 0):

In the method `initiate` you initialize the `output`, but in your static method `log` it's not guaranteed to have been initialized before calling since.

To be safe you should always initialize the required static variables either in the static method or as a field declaration.

In this case in your `initiate` it is possible to throw an exception prior to the line `output = new PrintWriter(logFile)` which means `output` is null